# How to automatically add a value to sheet 3 if not found in sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets

can anyone tell me how to add a value to sheet number 3 if the value is not found in sheet number 1? Should I use vlookup or something? I set up a very basic google form and corresponding google sheet for a spare bus and truck parts business. I would like to add a row to sheet number 3 for every part number that comes into sheet 1 from the google form, **that isn't already in sheet number 3**. And if possible have the other columns in the new row update information automatically as well.

Sheet number 1 records stock coming in, and sheet number 2 records stock being used, and sheet number 3 is supposed to update inventory records by adding stock coming in and subtracting stock being used. For this, I used the sumif function but there might be a **more efficient way** to do this as well? `=SUMIF('Parts In'!F:F,"*"&A3&"*",'Parts In'!E:E)-SUMIF('Parts Used'!E:E,"*"&A3&"*",'Parts Used'!C:C)`

Thanks

[Screenshot of sheet number 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TouOL.png)

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Done, thanks @player0

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet itself, and not just a screenshot?